# Create weekly reports to show how many patients Nurse A, B and Provider A, B saw

Tags: excel, ms-access, reporting, pivot-table

Below is an example of a dataset I have on which I need to report. I'm open to using either Excel or Access for this (currently, the dataset is in Excel format).

[image]

I need to create weekly reports to show how many patients Nurse A, B and Provider A, B saw. Then, I need to give % of "Yes" for each variable.

Ex. from 10/19-10/23, Nurse A saw 3 patients and was 66% complete in Var1, 66% complete in Var2, and 66% in Var3, etc.

Can this be done in a PivotTable or something similar?

Comment: How to know the values from 10/19-10/23 if there is not date in the sample data?

Comment: The dates are in the real dataset, I'm just giving a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest replacing the "Yes" with 1, and the "No" with 0.
Then do a pivot table using the average:

[image]

The decimals can then be formatted as percents.

Answer (score 0):

*As user is open to solutions I present this solution using only Excel Formulas, for user to be aware of this possibility...*

This solution assumes sample data is located at `B6:G11` *(adjust as required)*

**Summary for Nurses** : Located at `I6:M11` *(adjust as required)* with these fields:

**Nurse** : Extracts unique record for each nurse. Enter this `FormulaArray` in `I7` then copy till last record

*(Formulas Array are entered by pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously)*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$6:$C$11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(I$6:I6,$C$6:$C$11),0)*1),"")
```

**Patients** : Count of patients attended by each nurse. Enter this formula in `J7` then copy till last record

```
=IF(EXACT($I7,""),"",COUNTIF($C$6:$C$11,$I7))
```

**Var1, Var2 & Var3** : Percentage completed by each nurse. Enter this formula in `K7` then copy till last record then to `L7:M11`

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS($C$6:$C$11,$I7,E$6:E$11,"Yes")/$J7,"")
```

**Summary for Providers** : Located at `O6:S11` *(adjust as required)* with these fields:

**Provider** : Extracts unique record for each provider. Enter this `FormulaArray` in `O7` then copy till last record

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$D$11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(O$6:O6,$D$6:$D$11),0)*1),"")
```

**Patients** : Count of patients attended by each provider. Enter this formula in `P7` then copy till last record

```
=IF(EXACT($O7,""),"",COUNTIF($D$6:$D$11,$O7))
```

**Var1, Var2 & Var3** : Percentage completed by each provider. Enter this formula in `Q7` then copy till last record then to `R7:S11`

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS($D$6:$D$11,$O7,E$6:E$11,"Yes")/$P7,"")
```

[image]